# как узнать имя COM портов на python

Tags: python, com, com-port

Есть способ вывести все номера ком портов, но вот вывести имена ком портов я нигде инфы не нашёл. Мне нужно вывести список всех доступных COM портов и их имена. Либо как подключится к com порту по его имени

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Устанавливаем библиотеку pyserial:

```
pip install pyserial
```

Выводим имена портов:

```py
import serial.tools.list_ports

ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

for port in ports:
    print(port)
```

Comment: огроменное спасибо!